# Design time only JavaScript in Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm using the ESRI JavaScript API and ESRI conveniently provide a .js file that adds intellisense support.  To use it, you have to include an html  tag on the page that references the .js file exactly as you would any other js file.

However, this has the undesirable effect of the page then attempting to load the .js file when run.  This is undesirable as a) it's over 0.5MB and b) it seems to have some errors in it.

Is there a way that Visual Studio (2012) can some how strip out the  tag for this particular .js file when the project is run?  i.e. some sort of pre-processor command?

Thanks
Simon

Comment: With intellisense you can use `/// <reference path="referencefile.js" />` which will not be included in output but only while developing

Comment: For this you should first download the vsdoc of the api, which you can refer to.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I couldn't use the <reference> tag directly in the html page.  However, I created a .js file that just has the <reference> tag as per your example.  I reference that from my html page.  This allows the intellisense to function and means that when run, although my .js file is references, the vsdoc js file isn't.  IF you write this as an answer I can make it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the vsdoc of the API, then use

`/// <reference path="path/to/script/api-vsdoc.js" />`

in a js file. This enables IntelliSense but does not include the script at runtime.